# Topmost UITableView not receiving touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have two `UITableView`s in my view controller, both of them are loaded through container views, more or less the structure described below.

```
UIView
  - UIView "Header view" (No issues with this one)
    - UIStackview
  - Container view
    - UITableView "Table view 1"
  - UIView "Footer view"
    - UIStackview
      - ...
    - Container view (Initially off screen)
      - UITableView "Table view 2"
```

In the `viewDidLoad` function of "Table view 2", I'm connecting to the backend server to fetch some data. In the completion handler, the table view ("Table view 2") is populated and the "footer view" becomes draggable and gravity is applied to it (via a delegate function to the parent view controller).

In detail, a `UIDynamicAnimator`, `UIDynamicItemBehavior`, `UIGravityBehavior`, `UICollisionBehavior`, `UITapGestureRecognizer` as well as a`UIPanGestureRecognizer` is added to the footer view, to enable the user to drag it up from the bottom and see the entries. The dragging itself, as well as the gravity is working exactly as expected, however when I try to scroll the table view ("Table view 2"), the "Table view 1" is receiving the touch events.

Side note: for some reason I need to call `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.footerView];` in the `viewDidLoad` function, otherwise the footer view is presented below the "table view 1" sometimes. Maybe this is related, but I don't know how to solve it.

I have tried a bunch of stuff without success. Any help is appreciated!

**Clarification:**
The expected behavior is to only scroll the table view that is located in the footer view (i.e. "table view 2"), but the actual behavior is that the other table view ("table view 1") is being scrolled. I have also tried wrapping the UIStackview into another UIView and adding the tap and pan gesture recognizes to that instead, with the same result.

Comment: I'm assuming both UITableViews are wired and delegated to use the same delegate methods (number of rows, cell for row etc.)? It may be too simple but it sounds like the second table view is wired up incorrectly.

Comment: generally touch event disables when we implement  other gesture recognizer inside same vc, solution is for use delegate method of gesture recognizer to detect touch specifically.

Comment: @latenitecoder – Thanks for your input, however the two UITableView's have their own controllers with their own delegates, and both of them look good to me. Any ideas what could be wrong in particular?

Comment: @vaibhav – Thanks for your input as well. I have tried setting the delegate of the UIPanGestureRecognizer of "footer view". It gets called correctly if I tap/pan the stack view within the footer view, however it's not even called when trying to scroll in "table view 2". I have also tried setting the delegate of the table view 2's UIPanGestureRecognizer, but I get an angry error message saying "UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate", which I can understand. Any ideas how to handle the delegate?

Comment: This layout sounds a bit complicated to get my head around but to be honest i think the complexities are not the issue. You say that table view 1 is receiving touch events for table view 2 - Now I'm thinking you have not wired your tables up using UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. Is this the case? Using gesture recognisers on a table for anything other than gestures themselves seems a bad approach and the angry message would appear to be informing you that the scroll view (which is a composite component of a tableview) must have it's delegate set if using a gesture recogniser.

Comment: What is the tableviews (both 1 and 2) delegate pattern? - are you using number of rows in section, cell for row at index path and did select cell at index path? if not explain how you intend to manipulate both tables

Comment: @latenitecoder Both of the table views are within separate `UITableViewControllers` that is using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The population of the table views are working as intended. The row selection is disabled for both of them. The expected result is to only scroll the table view that is located in the footer view (i.e. "table view 2"), but the actual result is that the other table view ("table view 1") is being scrolled. I have also tried wrapping the UIStackview into another UIView and adding the tap and pan gesture recognizes to that instead, with the same result.